# Перенести в новую структуру результат програмы

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct word {
    char value[25];
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    char str[200], str1[200];
    int m = 0, k = 0;
    FILE *file, *file1, *file2;

    if( ( file = fopen( "text.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        puts( "Error" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    while( fgets( str, 200, file ) == NULL );

    fclose( file );
    char *ptr = strtok( str, ",.-!?" );

    while( ptr != NULL ) {
        cout << ptr;

        if( ( file1 = fopen( "new.txt", "a" ) ) == NULL ) {
            puts( "Error" );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        fputs( ptr, file1 );
        fclose( file1 );
        ptr = strtok( NULL, ",.-!?" );
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "ZZZ" << endl;

    if( ( file2 = fopen( "new.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        puts( "Error" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    fgets( str1, 200, file2 );

    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        if( str1[i] == ' ' ) {
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "AAA" << endl;
    cout << "The number of the words = " << k + 1 << endl;
    fclose( file2 );
    word *d = new word[k];

    if( ( file2 = fopen( "new.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        puts( "Error" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    while( fscanf( file2, "%s", d[m].value ) != EOF ) {
        m++;
    }

    fclose( file2 );

    for( int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++ ) {
        cout << d[i].value << endl;
    }

    cout << "ZZZ" << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++ ) {
        d[i].number = 1;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < k + 1; j++ ) {
            if( i != j ) {
                if( _stricmp( d[i].value, d[j].value ) == 0 ) {
                    d[i].number++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++ ) {
        if( d[i].number ) {
            cout << "The number of word which are the same with " << d[i].value << " " <<
                 d[i].number << endl;
        }
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Данная программа считает количество вхождений каждого слова в текст. В конце она выводит слово и количество. Проблема в том, что выводится каждое слово, при этом считает верно, но нужно по одному экземляру, чтобы затем записать в новый файл слово и количество. Хотел переписать слово и его количество вхождений в новую структуру по одному экземпляру, но не мог. Помогите.

Comment: Почему у вас три указателя на файл объявляется?:)

Comment: Что касается этого цикла while( fgets( str, 200, file ) == NULL ); то в лучшем случае в переменной str окажется последняя строка файла.

Comment: Все ошибки из предыдущего вопроса перекочевали 1:1 в этот. Почему вы игнорируете совет воспользоваться отладчиком и своими глазами на них посмотреть?

Comment: количество слов считает нормально

Comment: просто не могу записать результат в новую структуру

Comment: я здесь обьяснил новый вопрос

Comment: это вы проигнорировали этот

Comment: А вы всё-таки попробуйте приложить хоть минимум усилий самостоятельно. Как - рассказал и там, и здесь.